# How to find both duplicates and original in a C# List <T> LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

I read almost all answers on here regarding finding duplicates in a List type string in C#, but I haven't found really the solution I need.

Supposing I have a list :

`List<String> list = new List<String>{"6","1","2","4","6","5","1","2","1","2"};`

What I want to retrieve are the duplicate values and their originals, in a new list, so that the resulting list will be as follows:

`List<String> duplist = {"6","6","1","1","1,","2","2","2"};`

Comment: so where is problem?

Comment: so what code have you written to try to solve the problem?

Comment: Try group by and you will get what you want

Comment: do search before post https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=find%20duplicates%20in%20list%20string%20c%23

Comment: "...and their originals" What do you mean? The resultset is just the dupes

Comment: @LewsTherin; that meant that he wants to retain the count and order of the duplicates but remove all which are unique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first approach that comes to my mind is:

```
List<String> duplist = list
    .GroupBy(str => str)
    .Where(g=> g.Count() != 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

If anyone is interested, here is the query syntax:

```
var dups = from str in list
           group str by str into g
           where g.Count() != 1
           from str in g
           select str;

List<String> duplist = dups.ToList();
```

Comment: I was about to post the same with only difference `g.Count()>1`, you beat me to it +1

Comment: I also had the same answer, but I used linq sql-syntax :)

Comment: @Grundy: i guess it all comes down to `SelectMany`. So i think that OP already knew how to find the duplicates but not how to select all of them into a new collection.

Comment: @Dennis_E you can add it as yet another variant with query syntax

Comment: @Grundy I like this version better.

Comment: @Grundy: for that it's worth, i have added the query syntax.